# Windows redirect traffic to different DNS name not fixed IP address (hosts file equivalent)

Tags: windows, networking, redirection, hosts-file

Using the Windows hosts file, one can redirect traffic for a domain to a specific IP address, e.g.

> domainA.com --> 127.0.0.1

I am looking for a SIMPLE way to do the same, but for a target domain name not for a target IP address (as this is dynamic), I.e.

> domainA.com --> domainB.com

---

**Addition:**
After the getting some initial answers I think I need to concretise my question.

Situation: I have an application which looks up the IP of the target domain via DNS and then connects via HTTP to the IP address. I do not have control over any proxy settings.

**Option 1**
Basically I am looking for a way to:

- intercept DNS requests for a
  domainA.com
- launch a DNS request for a
  domainB.com
- serve the IP of domainB.com in
  response to the request for
  domainA.com

Without running an entire DNS server.

**Option 2**
If a DNS server is the only way, in the alternative I would also be happy with an solution to how to define a non-standard DNS-server for a single application. Any ideas for wrapper applications, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Third solution**

beside setting up a dns-server and injecting a hook into gethostbyname:

Register a script as a service which periodically resolves domainB.com and modifies the entry of domainA.com in the /etc/hosts file.
Since most dns entries does not change very often, it is sufficient to run the script on startup or once a day.

I am using such a script to update the domain-blocklist on my home computers.

Answer (score 5):

Edit - After re-reading your question, I do not think this will be possible without a local DNS server to point at as the hosts file only supports FQDN --> IP. However, I think your best bet will be Either some sort of local redirecting proxy server, or an addon that can rewrite host headers.

However, I wrote a guide you may be interested in, which will hopefully explain things a bit better to you...:

This isn't very easy to explain, so if you have any follow up questions, please write in comments and I will be happy to help:

This is not possible **BUT** putting the IP results in the exact same end result.

Remember, at the end of the day, all that happens when ever you target a FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) is that it translates that address to an IP address.

If you want to forward anyone visiting `domainA.com` to `domainB.com`, you simply put `domainB.com`'s ip as `domainA.com`'s entry in the hosts file.

This results in ANYTHING targeting/visiting `domainA.com` instead being redirected to `domainB.com`.

**HOWEVER** I am guessing you want to redirect a website. Websites are a lot more complicated than this, part of the protocol sends something known as a `Host Header`. This is where the web browser contacts the web server **AND** tells it the address it is trying to access.

For example, visiting Google.com shows the following:

[image]

(Notice the `Host:` line).

You can also visit Google.com via it's IP address - http://74.125.230.115 - This is because they have a default entry set up which services all requests **NOT** matching a host header.

So, when you visit `domainA.com` it is possible that `domainB.com` is only serving `domainB.com` content to someone with a host header set to `domainB.com`.

What you need to do is use a proxy server, Firewall (DPI), or some sort of addon that actually rewrites the Host Header/redirects. Alternatively, if you control the web server domainB.com , you simply need to add `domainA.com` to the addresses it will listen to - then any host header with `domainA.com` - it will respond with `domainB.com`'s content.

Adding addition host headers in IIS:

[image]

Comment: I believe you might be right that a DNS server is unavoidable. - Though I was hoping not. See the addition to my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can set up such [redirect actions with Privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#REDIRECT).

Comment: is this still possible if I do not have access to the application's proxy settings?

Comment: @ArikRaffaelFunke: Ah, your question has been updated, you'll need to run your own DNS server to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution to Option 2**

In case anybody else has this problem in future: It is possible to intercept DNS requests from a single application without using the hosts file which affects all functions.

See the CodeProject ["Intercept and Rewrite DNS Requests Using Regular Expressions"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/DnsHijack.aspx) by Dan Farino